# How I can check that user has already liked page without user_likes permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I also try get data from getSignedRequest() (PHP-SDK 3.4)  but page data is empty in response:

```
Array
(
  [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
  [code] => AQC94XuRCkLCYkJkBU2j2JvR_H0dEesyyWE9IOnBorRExZyjDhRR1M5JnG5CiWLf12xuO0CiFzVva05D-L3NNuId-IbOg4VO8X-DENRlbj3CiSIzBn....
  [issued_at] => 1408109031
  [user_id] => 6660247934796
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

See v2.1 updates, Fangates are not possible anymore, and not allowed according to the platform policy of Facebook.